# Force Reset Password after first time login

Tags: python, reactjs, aws-lambda

I am making a web application using Python, ReactJS , AWS lambda.

I want to force the user to change the password after first time login . How should i do with the backend change?

After resetting the password , it should redirect to normal page .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simple way is You can create a field as “firstLogin”, in table of users then after logged in for first time make it as a special value like “1” then check if value is “1” so user have to change the password, if successfully then redirect

Comment: Thanks for the response . Is it possible without creating a field in table?

Comment: @Aria5h4h The BaseUser has a field `last_login` already which can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table where you store Users, you can create a column to check whether the User is logging in the first time or not. This can be done by the following method, when the user is created, the value for the column firstLogin(of Type Date) would be set as NULL, and when the user logs in the first time, you can use a Date function to obtain the date and insert the value there.

So, here is the process in brief.

1. Make a HTTP request to create an account using fetch, axios, request or whatever module you like to create an account. Route: POST /user, with the body containing the values or data about the User. At backend, set the SQL statement to `INSERT INTO User(Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, FirstLogin) VALUES ("RAM", "KUMAR", "ramkumar", "iamaverysecurepassword", NULL);`
2. Now when the User logs in for the first time using your web application, make a call to the backend, using the following route: PATCH /user, to execute the following SQL Query `UPDATE User SET FirstLogin="{Value of Date}" WHERE Username="{Your username here(ramkumar)}";`
3. Now, when you have set the Date of the first login of the user, you redirect the User on your web application using `document.location.href={URL to normal page}"`
4. And then comes the condition, that if the user has not logged in the first time, how to redirect him to the password change page? You actually execute a SQL query again, to check whether it is the first time he is logging in or not. So, basically every time an action that requires the user to have logged in before, i.e, the first time. You check whether the FirstLogin column in your SQL has the value or is NULL for the corresponding user. `SELECT Firstname FROM User WHERE Username={your username here(ramkumar)};` Now check the value using if statement in your code, the value for the executed SQL Query and that FirstLogin contains a date or is null.